# How to send form with id using json ajex

Tags: ajax, jsp

i am creating simple crud system using jsp and ajex all working fine. only i  had a problem is when i tried to edit the data click edit button  selected row record passing  to the form successfully after made the changes then  click the button record not edit undefined i saw the msg on console.select row id is not passing to update.jsp page what i tried so far i written below. i attached the image screen shot also.

[image]

**when i click edit button select row code data successfully displayed**

```
function get_project_details(id) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "edit_return.jsp",
        data: {"a": id},
        success: function(msg) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg); 
            isNew = false
             project_id = obj[0].id;
            $("#studname").val(obj[0].name);
            $("#course").val(obj[0].course);
            $("#fee").val(obj[0].fee);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
        }  
    });
    return false;
    }
```

**i have do add the data and edit the at the same form**
isNew true mean add data false means edit the data

```
 if (isNew == true) {
            _url = 'add.jsp';
            _data = $('#frmProject').serialize();
            _method = 'POST';
        }
        else {
            _url = 'update.jsp',
                _data = $('#frmProject').serialize() + "', project_id:'" + project_id;



            _method = 'POST';
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: _method,
            url: _url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: _data,
            success: function (data) {

                get_all();

         if(isNew == true)
        {
                alert("success");
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("update");
            }
                console.log(data);



            },
```

Update.jsp

```
 <%



     JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
   String id = request.getParameter("project_id");      
   String studname = request.getParameter("studname");
   String course = request.getParameter("course");
   String  fee = request.getParameter("fee");

      Connection con;
      PreparedStatement pst;
      ResultSet rs;
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud", "root","");

      pst = con.prepareStatement("update records set name = ? ,course = ?,fee= ? where id = ?");
      pst.setString(1,studname);
      pst.setString(2,course);
      pst.setString(3,fee);
    pst.setString(4,id);
      pst.executeUpdate();
     obj.put("name", "Updated");
     list.add(obj);

    out.print(list.toJSONString());

    out.flush();      





    %>
```

**Update.jsp i checked project_id passed or not. display null.**

_data = $('#frmProject').serialize() + "', project_id:'" + project_id; this correct way pass data to update.jsp page

Comment: You need to use `&`  instead of `,` to add extra data i.e : `_data = $('#frmProject').serialize() + "&project_id=" + project_id;`

Comment: sir i did this sir. but  id is not passing to the update.jsp

Comment: from where did you got `project_id` which you have passed in ajax ,post that as well ,also try to `alert(project_id);` and check if has something in it or not

Comment: project_id = obj[0].id;  when i click edit button  get id and put the variable project_id this project_id i sending to update.jsp . function get_project_details(id)  code above can you check sir

Comment: alert and see if it has something in it or not i.e : `alert(project_id);` ,also here at end add `;` instead of `,` i.e :  `_url = 'update.jsp';`

Comment: sir i checked alert(project_id) but display alert as undefined

Comment: okay one way to solve this is instead of assigning i.e :`project_id = obj[0].id;` this way , you can have one `hidden field` in your form and you can assign `id` value to that `input field` just like you did for other `inputs` by doing that  you don't need to  add extra data and your id will also get passed .

Comment: sir working sir thanks a lotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.